# Does Excel accept the [check]?[true]:[false] notation, instead of =IF([check],[true],[false])

Tags: if-statement, excel-2010

I am wondering if excel accepts alternative notations for IF statements. It would highly streamline reading the formulas which get overly complicated with the brackets and all.

I'm looking for an alternative to

```
=IF([condition],[true],[false])
```

to something like

```
=[condition]?[true]:[false]
```

Does anyone know of something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe (and [documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/if-function-HP010342586.aspx) support this hypothesis) that there is no other way than using

```
=IF([condition],[true],[false])
```

syntax (unfortunately).